# StartScan - Error en Samsung S5

Tags: android

Este codigo por alguna razon no me funciona en un Samsung S5. Este es el codigo

```
private final BroadcastReceiver wifiScanReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {
        wifiList = wifiManager.getScanResults();
        showWifis();
    }
}
};

public void detectWifi() {
registerReceiver(wifiScanReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
wifiManager.startScan();
}
```

showWifis() lo que hace es mostrarme un Alert Dialog diciendome las redes y si toco una q se conecte, eso me funciona en todos los telefonos menos en un Samsung S5 pues me muestra el cartel en blanco. La apk tiene todos los permisos puestos, pues como dije me funciona perfectamente bien en otros terminales, alguna ayuda??

Comment: Especifica cual es realmente el problema, `wifiList` llega vacio? te explota? muestra el código de `showWifis()` a ver si estas haciendo algo mal. Con ese simple código que muestras ahí todo parece normal y no hay suficiente detalle para resolver tu problema. Edita tu pregunta y agrega algo mas.

Comment: @Andrespengineer creo que mencione que me llega en blanco.... no se que mas poner creo que esa es toda la logica del errorque mas debo agregar?? ya mencione que me funciona en otros terminales

Comment: que `targetSdkVersion` estas utilizando? Si estas utilizando API 23 o mayor debes tener el permiso `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`

Comment: estoy utilizando 7.1.1 (25)

Comment: lo tengo, tengo todos los permisos necesario... puesto que funciona en otros terminales

Comment: disculpenme es que no tenia activada la localizacion el celular me siento como un tonto

Comment: no te volví a responder porque realmente no se que estaba pasando, esos pequeños detalles nos pasa a todos. Buena suerte. Recuerda que puedes escribir una respuesta y autoaceptarla, esto para que la pregunta no quede abierta.